# docker build access host folder

Tags: docker, containers

on my centos7 host, I write a Dockerfile to build a image base on centos7:latest.
also on my centos7 host, there is a local yumrepo folder, there are many RPMs I need install to docker image, the total size is about 1GB.

in my Dockerfile, I need write repo url to /etc/yum.repos.d/local.yum, like: baseurl=file://home/local_yumrepo/.
then run "yum -y install 1.rpm 2.rpm..."
but dockerfile cannot access the host folder.

1. I search google and found somebody say docker build support "-v HOST_VOLUME:CONTAINER_VOLUME", but if I add "-v" option, docker build return errors, and [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for "docker build"  doesn't support "-v" option
2. I can run "python -m HttpServer" on my host folder, then I can write baseurl=http://HOST_IP:8000/local_repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/local.yum, then Dockerfile can access this server and install RPMs, but I don't want take this way, because multi-user are using this host, if one people run httpserver on port 8000, other people cannot run again. I want each people run docker build independently.
3. I can also run "COPY HOST_LOCAL_REPO CONTAINER_VOLUME", then write the /etc/yum.repos.d/local.yum as baseurl=file://CONTAINER_VOLUME/, then docker build can install RPMs correctly. but this will make my Docker image size is too large even "rm -rf" the container volume at the end of Dockerfile. it's not acceptable about the large size
4. the RPMs has dependency each other, even I just yum install 1.rpm, it will isntall 111.rpm 112.rpm 113.rpm...., so I don't know what rpms I really need, but what I am sure is all the rpms are in the local repo folder.

my question is: is there a way in Dockerfile can run "yum install host_repo_url" using file:// protocol?

thanks

Comment: PS, if I install docker as "yum install docker", the version is 1.10, but if I follow official guide to do "yum install docker-engine", the version is 1.12.5Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you may want to run your python HTTP server at some random port, and pass the port number in `--build-arg` to `docker build`. Choosing the random port can easily be wrapped in a shell script.

Note that you need at least Docker 1.9 to use `--build-arg`.

Comment: thanks your comments.actually I don't want to use HTTP server way,

Comment: thanks your comments. I can get random port and pass the port to docker build command, but actually I don't want to use HTTP server way. I prefer to docker build can access host folder just like "docker run -v" options.